# Using Azure AD B2C in Xamarin.iOS with simulator - Problem with keychain (the Team ID is null)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app, and setting up Azure AD B2C for auth. I'm following the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c#register-your-mobile-application-with-azure-active-directory-b2c).
Everything works flawlessly for Andorid, but I'm facing an issue with th iOS project.

I've setup everything mentioned in the tutorial but that is not enough. In [this post](https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/xamarin/xamarin.forms/2019/07/01/sign-in-with-microsoft-account-with-xamarin-en.html), it describes how you should configure the **iOS Bundle Signing** to reference as custom entitlement **Entitlements.plist**. Otherwise you get this error:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: The application cannot
> access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (the TeamId is
> null). This is needed to enable Single Sign On between applications of
> the same publisher. This is an iOS configuration issue. See
> https://aka.ms/msal-net-enable-keychain-access for more details on
> enabling keychain access.

Well, if you do that using the Simulator, it doesn't work since apparently, you cannot set in iOS Bundle Signing configuration any custom Entitlement when using the simulator (commented [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30478/provisioning-problems-for-ios-simulator)).

Does this mean that I cannot test Azure AD B2C in the iOS simulator?

**Edit**: It seems you cannot set the custom Entitlement if you don't have an Apple Developer Program signing identity. Does this mean that I cannot test Azure AD B2C in the iOS simulator without being enrolled in the Apple Development Program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use custom entitlements including keychain access groups in iOS Simulator. It's done the same way you set custom entitlements for a device build, it's just disabled for simulator by default. Steps:

1. Modify your custom `Entitlements.plist` to include keychain access groups:

   ```
   <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
   <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. Apply the entitlements to the iOS Simulator configuration in project settings:

[image]

Once you have this in place, the MSAL library will be able to access that keychain group to store secrets in between app launches.

Comment: You're right. I missed an important point in my question: is it possible without paying the Apple Developer Program?
I guess not, since you need to set the Signing Identity.

Comment: @JuliusSD Hi, if the answer be helpful., remember to mark it when you have time. It will be helpful for others who have the same problem.

Comment: @JuliusSD in order to run on the simulator, you don't need an apple dev subscription so you can build and test on the simulator as is. If you want to do it on an ios device, you need a signed package and to get that profile you need an apple dev subscription.

Comment: Yeah, I can run the app in my simulator, what I cannot do is setup AAD B2C without the Apple Dev program :( because it needs to enable the keychain group

Comment: For iOS sim, there is no need to have a dev account, have you tried to configure as on my screenshot above? Set the developer automatic settings and try to run on simulator (it won't work on device but will work on sim). If you experience an error, please post it in your question for further investigation.