# Xamarin forms : Could not find any available provisioning profiles for IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, profile, simulator, provisioning

after a lot of time searching a solution to my problem, I turn to you for help.

When I'm trying to use SecureStorage in my Xamarin Forms project, all work good on android but when I compile on IOS Simulator, there is this an error message : "Error adding record: MissingEntitlement".

I found the solution for this error, I just follow the Microsoft documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios

[Keychain enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XnpV.png)

[Signature of bundle ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuXfE.png)

and now, there is an another error message : Could not find any available provisioning profiles for IOS.

Then, I created an Apple Developer account, go to my appaired Mac and start Xcode, and connect my apple Developer account to Xcode. But the error persist on Visual Studio for Windows.

I have tried all the solutions I have found but nothing works.
I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: You  need to login your apple account on VS for windows . **Tools ->Options -> Xamarin ->Apple Accounts**.

Comment: I already tried to login on VS, but I have a button "Install fastlane", when i click on the button I have an error message : "An error occurred while downloading fastlane. Try  again."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SecureStorage` on the iOS simulator even without Apple Dev account. For that, you need valid entitlements associated with your simulator build. I have described that in my similar response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995697/using-azure-ad-b2c-in-xamarin-ios-with-simulator-problem-with-keychain-the-te?answertab=votes#tab-top) and in official [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios):

1. Modify your custom Entitlements.plist to include keychain access groups:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
     <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)xxx.xxx.xxx</string>
</array>
```

2. Apply the entitlements to the iOS Simulator configuration in project settings:

[image]

Comment: I modified my custom Entitlements to <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.companyname.AppliMobileDepot</string>, and modified my project Bundle Signing like on the picture, but that not resolve the problem. What can I do ?

Comment: @oguzhan.cblt please provide the screenshots of that configuration in your questions, I’ll review it